# PHPunit - Missing class, although autoload.php is loaded

Tags: phpunit, autoload, bootstrapping

I've got the following file structure:

- includes

  - class.Klasse.php
- src

  - autoload.php
- tests

  - KlasseTest.php

This structure is within a project folder. On the linux shell, being in this folder, I type the following command line:

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/KlasseTest.php
```

The command line is showing me this:

```
PHPUnit 4.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Klasse' not found in /home/doug/workspace/PHPunit/tests/KlasseTest.php on line 7
```

My autload.php:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
   include 'includes/class.' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

My KlasseTest.php:

```
<?php
class KlasseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testWertvergleich() {
    $o = new Klasse();
  }
}
```

My class.Klasse.php:

```
<?php
class Klasse {
  public function __construct() {

  }
}
```

I don't know why I am getting the message above.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Really wish this had an answer. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

In `src/autoload.php`, use:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include __DIR__ . '/../includes/class.' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

The autoloader searches the classes in directories relative to the location of the autoload.php file. `__DIR__` ensures that the starting point of the file inclusion is always the directory of `autoload.php` - from there, you move one directory up (`/..`), and then inside the `includes` directory.